# Why would a bulb need a 30mA RCD for the bathroom?

Tags: lighting, bathroom

So I have bought a new light fitting for our shower room ([This is the bulb.](http://www.diy.com/departments/diall-gu10-7w-led-reflector-spot-light-bulb-pack-of-2/841191_BQ.prd?tab=reviews))

On the instructions it says if fitting in a bathroom a 30mA RCD is required. We have a fairly old fuse box, so wired fuses no RCDs. I see the lighting circuit has a 5A fuse on it. Does this actually equate to a 5,000mA RCD?

Does this mean the light fitting is no good for our circuit? Would I need to wire up a whole new circuit just for this light? Why would fitting it in the bathroom affect the size of RCD required?

Comment: Can I presume you are in a 240V country?

Comment: Yes - United Kingdom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of UK law (I am not a lawyer) is that like-for-like replacement does not require you to bring an electrical installation up to current standards.

I'd interpret that to mean I can change an incandescent lightbulb to an LED bulb, of same or lower real wattage (not equivalent wattage), in the same fitting, without needing to worry about RCD protection.

I would make sure that the fitting is properly earthed (assuming it has metal parts) and that people using the bathroom cannot reach the light fitting.

I would also make sure that the fitting allows for adequate flow of air around the bulb as LED-based bulbs seem to need cooling much more than incandescent bulbs do.

Comment: Thanks, I have fitted the light. Reading around about RCDs they do sound quite useful. We will probably update our fuse box shortly.

Answer (score 2):

An RCD is different from a fuse.  An RCD (residual current device) is known as a GFI (ground fault interrupter) or GFCI (ground fault current interrupting) device in the US.

In non-technical terms, if the RCD device sees current "missing" on a circuit - more leaving than returning - it shuts down power, based on the idea that that missing current may be starting a fire or shocking someone.

A 30ma RCD trips when 30ma of current is "missing."  In some locations, a 30ma trip is the maximum allowable for personal protection, prevention of electrical shock injuries.

RCD / GFCI are especially important in bathrooms because people are in contact with water and pipes, which increases electrical hazards.

Comment: I see. So would you use an RCD in place of a fuse? Would you generally keep your bathroom lights on a different circuit to the rest of the lights because of this?

Comment: In the US, if the panel isn't too old, you can usually buy a GFCI circuit breaker to replace the plain one in the panel.  I believe similar devices are available for not-too-old panels in the UK.  In the states, another option is to install a GFCI device somewhere in the circuit, wired to add GFI protection downstream.  This can be a "deadface" GFCI, or a GFCI receptacle.  I do not know if that's an option for you, hopefully someone better versed in the rules and products in the UK will chime in.

Comment: In the UK, an MCB in a CU can only be replaced by an RCBO, not with a plain RCD. The RCBO combines both functions - residual current detection (e.g. earth leakage) and, crucially, overcurrent detection to prevent fires starting in circuits e.g. due to too-many high-power appliances simultaneously operating on a ring circuit. If you buy a [new CU](http://www.screwfix.com/p/wylex-10-way-high-integrity-consumer-unit-10-mcbs/66470) it is likely to include one or two RCDs that each protect a *group* of MCBs (AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a very nice question to every electrician and Electrical personals but I would like to say that you can choose to ignore the rcd if only u have proper and quality earthing system to all your exposed metal work[image]rccb

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! I'm not sure how this answers the question. Would you please add something to explicitly show how this addresses the original question. Also, feel free to take the [tour] and spend some time in the [help] to get a feel for how things work around here.